# Area chart with black contour with gradient filling in c3.js

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have area chart with gradient color. But I need that my contour always was solid black.

Code:

```
<Chart id={'graph'}
oninit={ () => {
  ChartData[0]['desired'] = desired;
  ChartData[ChartData.length-1]['desired'] = desired;
  const gradient = d3.select('svg')
    .append("linearGradient")
    .attr('id', 'gradient')
    .attr('x1', '40%').attr('y1', '0%')
    .attr('x2', '50%').attr('y2', '100%');

  gradient
    .append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '30%')
    .attr('stop-color', '#000000')
    .attr('stop-opacity', '1');

  gradient
    .append('stop')
    .attr('offset', '100%')
    .attr('stop-color', '#FFFFFF')
    .attr('stop-opacity', '1');
}}
legend= {{show:false}}
padding= {{
 right: 30,
 left: 50}}
data= {{
  json: ChartData,
  labels: true,
  keys: {
    x: 'date',
    value:  ['value','desired']
  },
  colors: {
    value:'url(#gradient)',
    desired: 'red'
  },
  types:{
    value:'area-spline',
    desired:'line'
  },
```

What I have: [image]

As you can see, in low points, contour is almost white, what is not appropriate to my requirements.

Comment: Quite easy to fix with simple CSS.

Comment: @dfsq i tried .c3-line {
    stroke: black !important;

but then my red line turns into black

Comment: Fixed.
Just add to CSS

.c3-line-[column-name] {
    stroke-width: 1.5px !important;
    stroke: black !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
Just add to CSS

```
.c3-line-[column-name] {
    stroke-width: 1.5px !important;
    stroke: black !important;
}
```